# Can't "store member function" in template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to "store member function in my class" in order to call it later in some cases. But I can't fix my code for storing member functions with parameters. Heres is my code:

```
class IMemFn
{
public:
    IMemFn() {}
    IMemFn(const IMemFn& other) = delete;
    IMemFn& operator=(const IMemFn& other) = delete;
    IMemFn(IMemFn&& other) = delete;
    IMemFn& operator=(IMemFn&& other) = delete;
    virtual ~IMemFn() {}

    virtual void func(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) = 0;
};

template<typename ReturnType, class Class>
class MemFn final : public IMemFn
{
public:
    typedef ReturnType(Class::*Method)();

    MemFn(Class* object, Method method) : IMemFn(), m_object(object), m_method(method) {};

    virtual void func(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) override final
    {
        (m_object->*m_method)(name, value);
    };

private:
    Class* m_object;
    Method m_method;
};



class Test
{
public:
    template <class Class, typename Method>
    void addMemFn(Class* obj, Method method) {
        auto memFn = new MemFn<typename std::result_of<decltype(method)(Class)>::type, Class>(std::forward<Class*>(obj), std::forward<Method>(method));
        m_memFns.push_back(memFn);
    }

private:
    std::list<IMemFn*> m_memFns;
};


class SomeClass
{
public:
    void funcAll(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) { std::cout << "SomeClass func"; }
};

class SomeClass2
{
 public:
     void func2(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) { std::cout << "SomeClass2 func"; }
};


int main()
{
    Test test;
    SomeClass someClass;
    SomeClass2 someClass2;

    test.addMemFn(&someClass, &SomeClass ::funcAll);
    test.addMemFn(&someClass2, &SomeClass2::func2);

    return 0;
}
```

But compilation fails with this message: `'type': is not a member of 'std::result_of<Method (Class)>`

and in this line: `(m_object->*m_method)(name, value);`

But if I try to save member function without parameters, then this error doesn't appear.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to avoid `std::mem_fn`?

Comment: Why not use a [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? Also look into `std::bind` and lambda functions.

Comment: Look at implementation of `std::function` for inspiration.

Comment: @JesperJuhl looks like a learning exercise to me.

Comment: @n.m., I know and I need to store functions only with 2 const std::string&

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get the compiler to determine the parameter types to the member function you're trying to bind. With overloading, this is impossible.

Comment: `std::result_of<decltype(method)(Class)` This is wrong because `method` is not callable with one argument of type `Class`, it needs two more arguments of type `std::string&`.

Comment: `ReturnType(Class::*Method)();` This is also wrong because the method takes two parameters of type `std::string&` so `()` doesn't represent its argument list.

Comment: Of course if this is *not* a learning exercise, just use `std::function`.

Answer (score 1):

Several changes required here to make it compile:

- Firstly `std::result_of<decltype(method)(Class)` needs to be `std::result_of<Method(Class*,std::string,std::string)`
  because it is a member function taking a pointer to `this` plus two arguments.
- It looks like function `inform` in MemFn should be renamed `func`.
- `Method` needs to be added as a template argument of `MemFn`.

Then you can invoke the member functions through the `test` object, for example:

`(*test.m_memFns.begin())->func("a", "b");`

However you will not be able to return different types from these member functions while also satisfying the interface `void IMemFn::func(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's everybody for your answers! Seems I'm very tired 'cause of these damn tamplates. I used std::functions with std::bind and everything now is simple and light. So, my final code is:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <class Class, typename Method>
    void addMemFn(Class* obj, Method method) {
        auto func = std::bind(method, obj, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
        m_funcs.push_back(func);
    }

private:
    std::list<std::function<void(const std::string&, const std::string&)>> m_funcs;
};


class SomeClass
{
public:
    void funcAll(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) { std::cout << "SomeClass func"; }
};

class SomeClass2
{
public:
    void func2(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) { std::cout << "SomeClass2 func"; }
};


int main()
{
    Test test;
    SomeClass someClass;
    SomeClass2 someClass2;

    test.addMemFn(&someClass, &SomeClass::funcAll);
    test.addMemFn(&someClass2, &SomeClass2::func2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can improve things further by removing `std::bind` in favor of a lambda